# Dans quel cadre le pronom relatif « qui » apparaît-il plus fréquemment que « lequel » et dans quelle proportion ?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs, lexique, registre-soutenu, fréquence-utilisation

*Qui* pronom relatif représentant, à titre de complément, est concurrencé par *lequel* (LBU §714 a). « Quand il s'agit de personnes, l'usage soigné préfère *qui* [...] » (LBU §720 b) ; « [l]orsque l'antécédent est une personne, on emploie plus souvent le pronom relatif *qui*, bien que *lequel* soit possible en pareil cas » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3508)).

Quand il s'agit de personnes, *qui* est-il plus fréquent que *lequel* ou l'est-il davantage surtout dans l'usage soigné ? Dans quelle proportion ?

Comment: en langage courant, "qui" est beaucoup plus utilisé que "lequel" quand il s'agit de personnes. Du moins en Belgique...

Comment: @Montéedelait Merci pour la récompense, même si ça n'a pas produit les résultats escomptés...

Comment: Dommage que personne n'ait tenté sa chance ou pu trouver une stratégie fructueuse. Je continuerai d'y réfléchir, et peut-être un jour ou une nuit, dans un mois ou cinq ans, l'inspiration me visitera-t-elle.

Answer (score 2):

Disons que **qui** représente toute personne et **lequel** se rapporte plus aux objets ou la sélection d'une entité (personne ou objet)

Par exemple

1. `Qui a vidé mon portefeuille ?`
2. `Qui parmi vous a vidé mon portefeuille ?`
3. `Lequel d'entre vous a vidé mon portefeuille ?`

Dans ces trois exemples **qui** peut être utilisé mais son usage le plus approprié est dans le 1er exemple.

Dans l'exemple 1 **qui** est vague et sous-entend le 2

Dans le 2 **qui** est toujours vague mais circonscrit "pourrait être quelqu'un parmi vous"

Dans le 3 **qui** est précis et remplacé par **lequel** parce-que je suis sûr que "le coupable est parmi vous" maintenant il reste à choisir celui dont il s'agit

**MODIFICATIONS**

Je conclus en disant que **qui** peut intervenir à la place de **lequel** ... Tout dépendra du registre et du contexte

Comment: La question portait sur les subordonnées relatives, pas sur les questions.

Comment: Merci, ma réponse n'est pas directe, en fait il s'agit de la fréquence de l'usage de **qui** et je me suis efforcé de oui montrer combien **qui** pourrait influencer par sa présence manifeste ou non

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je crois bien que le sens reste inchangé que l'on mette **d'entre** ou **de** ... Dans cette phrase **de** est un *article partitif*, ce qui conserve le sens globale ...

Comment: @Fólkvangr Un ngram montre que « Lequel d'entre vous » est beaucoup plus courant; de plus, je trouve personnellement que « entre » est plus expressif, bien que je ne sache pas dire pourquoi. (champ 1)

Comment: @Fólkvangr [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lequel+d%27entre+vous%2CLequel+de+vous%2CLequel+parmi+vous&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLequel%20d%27%20entre%20vous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLequel%20de%20vous%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CLequel%20d'%20entre%20vous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLequel%20de%20vous%3B%2Cc0) (fin)